# Prevent delete array of object adding again in realm db

Tags: swift, realm

I have an api who fetch data and add it in realm, what i want is whenever i delete realm object and refresh the page and called the api. the object that already delete is not showing/adding again in realm db. How to do it? here is my code

```
class TickerRealmStorage: RealmStorage, TickerStorage {
    private var items = RealmSwift.List<Ticker>()
    private var temptTicker: Ticker?

    func get() -> RealmSwift.List<Ticker> {
        return items
    }

    func save(messages: [Message]) {
        messages.forEach { message in
            let ticker = Ticker()
            ticker.campaignID = message.campaignID
            ticker.isRead = message.isRead
            ticker.messageBody = message.body

            if let temptTicker = temptTicker, ticker.campaignID == temptTicker.campaignID {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(ticker)
                }
            }
            items.append(ticker)
        }

        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(items, update: .modified)
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to save tickers")
        }
    }

    func delete(ticker: Ticker) {
        temptTicker = ticker
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(ticker)
        }
    }
}
```

Should i add a temptItems so i check if the data already delete not adding into list items.

Comment: You need a logic to keep track of things you don't want to add. How's  a database suppose to know that the previously deleted item should not be added?

Comment: The question is unclear; if an object is deleted from Realm, `ticker` in this case` it's well.. deleted. You can't get it back. So under what circumstances do you think it could be re-added? The code has a number of other issues; if a Realm object is deleted from disk, it's also removed from memory and attempts to access it will crash. e.g. deleting ticker `realm.delete(ticker)` and then attempting to add it `items.append(ticker)` will crash. Oh, and since ticker is not managed `let ticker = Ticker()` attempting to delete an unmanaged object will also crash.

Comment: it re-added when i refresh the page which is called an API, yes it's true. it crash whenever i delete, since i'm new to realm. i still figuring out how to handle the crash @Jay

Comment: Handle the crash by preventing it in the first place. e.g. don't add an object that's been deleted. Also, it's 'odd' that in in a save function, it also deletes - that should really be separate. Last thing I would suggest is you've got a lot of code wrapped into this TickerRealmStorage class, and it doesn't really seem like that's necessary. Why create a class that gets data but if it goes out of scope, that data becomes nil? Is this a singleton? I suggest look at the tutorials [Quick Start](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/) guide to get more comfortable with Realm.